# Android TextView autolink modify phone number detection?

Tags: android

Is there a way to change how the detection of `autoLink` TextView finds phone numbers?

Thing is, it detects international format quite well, like `+49123456789` but it fails on local formatted numbers like 0699777666555 (without a preceeding "+" character).

We need to have those numbers available too.

The TextView is set up with `autoLink="all"`

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... some other settings ...
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:textColorLink="@color/darkblue"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

We have internal numbers (like 5532) and local phone numbers without any prefixes like 12345678. It would be great, if they can be highlighted too, without any, or at least without too much coding involved.

Any solutions to this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: android:autoLink="web|email|phone"

Comment: "all" covers all those three. It *does* show phone numbers, but not in all required formats. Please read the question closely, thank you.

Comment: I'd like to add, that android 6+ seems to find those numbers correctly, but not older versions. But the question stays the same - we need to modify this, so that older versions find those numbers too.

Comment: you can check the number and add `+` also use `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(unformattedNumber);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this programatically:

```
public class AutoLinkifyTextView extends TextView {

    public AutoLinkifyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutoLinkifyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        super.setText(text);
        parseLinks();
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(int stringRes) {
        super.setText(stringRes);
        parseLinks();
    }

    private void parseLinks() {
        Linkify.addLinks(this, Linkify.ALL);
    }

}
```

and then use  `AutoLinkifyTextView` instead of TextView

Comment: Interesting approach - I will play around with this a bit - Thank you very much for this suggestion!

Comment: yes it worked quite fine - i just put code in the setText, replacing " 0" (blank+number zero) with " +xx" where xx is the local country international number and all links are correct now. Thank you very much - i will accept that answer. In fact I search for more patterns how a local number can start, so " 0" was just an example to keep my answer short here. But yes, all is good now :)